# What happens when you join on an "or" or in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Given this simple schema:

```
create table A(pk int primary key, R1 int, R2 int);
create table B(pk int primary key);
```

What exactly happens if I do the following query and join using an OR as shown below?

```
select *
from A
join B
on A.R1 = B.pk or A.R2 = B.pk
```

I'm interested in the following case:

What if a row exists where both R1 and R2 point to different PKs in B?  Do I end up with multiple records as a result of the join, or does it just default to the left side of the or and match the A.R1 = B.pk?

---

PS: I'm reading code on a tablet and don't have a DB to test it on, so please don't tell me to run it myself :) I tried googling but didn't find the exact situation.

Comment: You will end up with duplicate records from A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get two rows.

If you have Internet, you always have a database to hand [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b053/1) - the link is to the answer to your question.

Comment: Awesome, thanks man.  I completely forgot about SQL Fiddle; someone showed me that a few months ago.  I'll have to start using it :)